# how to loop through a foreach and return to a condition instead of processing it every iteration?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have a series of processes that handle items in a warehouse, now, the problem is that if the item is pending in an inventory adjustment operation, it should not allow a purchase/sale to be processed.

My intention is to go through the items of a sale, check if there is any pending in a stock adjustment and if so, not let the operation be processed until the adjustment is approved/rejected, but I am not succeeding, since I don't know how to loop through everything before processing a condition.

For now I have:

```
    @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
        @if ($detalleventa->articulo->ajusinv == 'y')           
             <a class="jsgrid-button btn btn-warning">
                Ajuste pendiente <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
             </a>
             @break                               
        @else
             <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('cambio.estado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                title="Aprobar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
             </a>
             <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" href="{{ route('cambio.rechazado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                title="Rechazar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
             </a>
       @endif
@endforeach
```

But it is repeating the approve and reject buttons to me as follows:

[image: repeated buttons]

My table is:

```
            <table id="order-listing"
            class="table venta .table-hover table-striped mt-0.5 table-bordered shadow-lg dt-responsive">
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" width='10px'>ID</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='50px'>Fecha</th>                        
                    <th scope="col" width='80px'>Empleado</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='10px'>#</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='350px'>Artículos</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='70px'>Almacenes</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='100px'>Estado</th>
                    <th scope="col" width='165px'>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($ventas as $venta)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $venta->id }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($venta->created_at)->format('d-m-y') }}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ ucwords($venta->cliente->nombre) }} {{$venta->cliente->apellido}}</td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
                                {{$detalleventa->cantidad}} <br>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                        
                        <td style="width: 50px;">
                            @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
                            • {{$detalleventa->articulo->nombre}} <br>
                            @endforeach
                            
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
                                {{$detalleventa->almacen->nom_alm}} <br>
                            @endforeach

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning text-bold" target="_blank">Por aprobar</a>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;">
                            @can('cambio.estado.ventas')
                                @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
                                    @if ($detalleventa->articulo->ajusinv == 'y')           
                                        <a class="jsgrid-button btn btn-warning">
                                            Ajuste pendiente <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        @break                               
                                    @else
                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('cambio.estado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                                            title="Aprobar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" href="{{ route('cambio.rechazado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                                            title="Rechazar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endcan
                            @can('ventas.pdf')
                                <a href="{{ route('ventas.pdf', $venta) }}" class="btn btn-secondary text-bold" title="Imprimir"
                                    target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a>
                            @endcan

                            @can('ventas.show')
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.ventas.show', $venta) }}" class="btn btn-info" title="Ver detalles"><i
                                        class="fas fa-eye"></i> </a>
                            @endcan
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you provide more table context code (td. tr, tbody etc)?

Comment: @dz0nika there it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution was to use `@php(count=0)` and if the condition applies the counter goes up and then the `if` depends on that number

```
@php($count=0)
@foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
    @if ($detalleventa->articulo->ajusinv == 'y')           
        @php($count++)
    @endif
@endforeach
@if ($count >= 1)           
    <a class="jsgrid-button btn btn-warning">
        Ajuste pendiente <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </a>
    @break                               
@else
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('cambio.estado.ventas', $venta) }}"
        title="Aprobar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" href="{{ route('cambio.rechazado.ventas', $venta) }}"
        title="Rechazar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
    </a>
@endif
```